# Are multiple Cookie headers allowed in an HTTP request?

Tags: http, cookies

Usually, a browser groups cookies into a single `Cookie` header, such as:

```
Cookie: a=1; b=2
```

Does the standard allow to send these as separate headers, such as:

```
Cookie: a=1
Cookie: b=2
```

Or do they always have to be on the same line?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Chanced upon this page while looking for details on the topic. A quote from `HTTP State Management Mechanism`, [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.4) ought to make things clearer:

**5.4.  The Cookie Header**

> When the user agent generates an HTTP request, the user agent MUST
> NOT attach more than one Cookie header field.

It looks like the use of multiple `Cookie` headers *is*, in fact, prohibited!

Comment: These crazy new-fangled RFC's. :)

Comment: Note that the _server_ can respond with multiple `Set-Cookie` headers: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#page-7

Comment: Downvoted because answer still yet does not explain how to have multiple cookies in one header.

Comment: Why the downvote, as OP specifically asked in terms of HTTP request, not HTTP response. @JeffDavenport

Comment: For those coming here from Google like Jeff, OP shows you can have multiple vars by separating them with ";" (a space is not needed)

Comment: @HawkeyeParker - *can* does not imply *correct*.  I would argue that `Set-Cookie:a=b;c=d;` is more correct than `Set-Cookie:a=b; Set-Cookie:c=d;` if the values are set by a single server. The spec says the server should not fold multiple Set-Cookie header fields into one **field**, but it can add multiple Set-Cookie header fields into one **response**. What that means in the real world is that when a proxy server passes along a response, if that proxy sets cookies, it should use a separate Set-Cookie header.

Comment: @Golphy thank you. You are absolutely correct. I misinterpreted the spec. Comment deleted.

Comment: See also @wusatosi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305814/are-multiple-cookie-headers-allowed-in-an-http-request/49409403#49409403)  from 5 years later, how HTTP 2 now apparently allows setting multiple cookie headers.

Comment: @Sz. this appears to internal to compressed HTTP 2, no? You still would construct a cookie using a semicolon, and similarly you'd get semicolon-separated cookies out after HTTP 2 has been decompressed (as said in the HTTP/2 RFC).

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan, as I interpreted it, the cookie header is allowed to be split (to help compression), it's just to be rejoined "before being passed into a non-HTTP/2 context, such as an HTTP/1.1", i.e. only for legacy stuff, to support backward compat.

Comment: @Sz. right (and the following isn't definite), but HTTP/2 is an "optimized expression" of HTTP semantics, while HTTP/1.1 is both an expression (the plain-text format) and a semantics (meaning of the text).

In other words, while separate cookie headers might exist from a reverse proxy to the client, then I don't think a back-end server nor client-side JavaScript ever see the packed HTTP/2 encoding, but both work within the HTTP/1.1 textual format.

Answer (score 49):

it's now allowed in HTTP/2 ([RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.5)), which specifies:

```
    8.1.2.5.  Compressing the Cookie Header Field

   The Cookie header field [COOKIE] uses a semi-colon (";") to delimit
   cookie-pairs (or "crumbs").  This header field doesn't follow the
   list construction rules in HTTP (see [RFC7230], Section 3.2.2), which
   prevents cookie-pairs from being separated into different name-value
   pairs.  This can significantly reduce compression efficiency as
   individual cookie-pairs are updated.

   To allow for better compression efficiency, the Cookie header field
   MAY be split into separate header fields, each with one or more
   cookie-pairs.  If there are multiple Cookie header fields after
   decompression, these MUST be concatenated into a single octet string
   using the two-octet delimiter of 0x3B, 0x20 (the ASCII string "; ")
   before being passed into a non-HTTP/2 context, such as an HTTP/1.1
   connection, or a generic HTTP server application.

   Therefore, the following two lists of Cookie header fields are
   semantically equivalent.

     cookie: a=b; c=d; e=f

     cookie: a=b
     cookie: c=d
     cookie: e=f
```

Comment: What's the reason for `If there are multiple Cookie header fields after
   decompression, these MUST be concatenated into a single octet string`? Compatibility? Surely there is no practical advantage when dealing with a "generic HTTP server application".

Comment: @ioquatix: If you look at the accepted answer, you can see it's because multiple `Cookie` headers are prohibited by the older spec (before HTTP/2).  So you must concatenate them when passing to an old server or you will be violating the spec, and it may lead to unpredictable behaviour (e.g. a HTTP/1.1 proxy server might drop the extra duplicate headers).