# Add cookies to retrofit 2 request

Tags: android, cookies, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to add cookies with retrofit 2.0. If i understand correct, cookies - the same as headers. this cookies must be added:

```
private HashMap<String, String> cookies = new HashMap();
cookies.put("sessionid", "sessionId");
cookies.put("token", "token");
```

this one work with Jsoup lib:

```
String json = Jsoup.connect(apiURL + "/link")
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .execute()
                    .body();
```

here is my code with retrofit request:

```
@GET("link")
Call<CbGet> getData(@Header("sessionid") String sessionId, @Header("token") String token);
```

but it is doesn't work...
i get 403 error code so there are no cookies in the request...

any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881775/automatic-cookie-handling-with-okhttp-3

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First of all: cookie is not the same as a header. Cookie is a special HTTP header named **Cookie** followed by list of the pairs of keys and values (separated by ";"). Something like:

```
Cookie: sessionid=sessionid; token=token
```

Since [you cannot set multiple Cookie headers in the same request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305814/are-multiple-cookie-headers-allowed-in-an-http-request) you are not able to use two *@Header* annotations for separate values (*sessionid* and *token* in your sample). I can think of one **very hacky** workaround:

```
@GET("link")
Call<CbGet> getData(@Header("Cookie") String sessionIdAndToken);
```

You change your method to send sessionId and token in one string. So in this case you should manually generate cookie string beforehand. In your case sessionIdAndToken String object should be equal to "sessionid=*here_goes_sessionid*; token=*here_goes_token*"

The **proper solution** is to set cookies by adding **OkHttp**'s (that is library Retrofit uses for making underlying http calls) [request interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors). You can see solution or adding custom headers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963394/how-to-use-interceptor-to-add-headers-in-retrofit-2-0).

Answer (score 21):

why not using the cookieJar option?

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .client(
        new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .cookieJar(new SessionCookieJar()).build())
    .build();

private static class SessionCookieJar implements CookieJar {

    private List<Cookie> cookies;

    @Override
    public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
        if (url.encodedPath().endsWith("login")) {
            this.cookies = new ArrayList<>(cookies);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
        if (!url.encodedPath().endsWith("login") && cookies != null) {
            return cookies;
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add: `this.cookies.addAll(cookies);` inside the `saveFromResponse` method

Comment: No. You wouldn't want to add to the cookies. You would want to completely reset the cookies in `saveFromResponse`.

Answer (score 5):

API web service example add Header

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("getDriverRoutes")
Call<Guzergah> getGuzergah(@Header("Cookie") String userCookie, @Field("driver_id") int driver_id);
```

when you login to system save cookies to your local on Response like

```
 public void onResponse(Response<Login> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            hidepDialog();
            String cookie = response.headers().get("Set-Cookie");
            editor.putString("user_cookie", cookie.split(";")[0]);
            editor.commit();
```

and in every service you need to be autorised send your cookies , get from sharepreference and send it with your web service

```
  String userCookie = shp.getString("user_cookie", ""); // here is cookies before send
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://server.aracadabra.com:8080/").
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    final APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    final Call<SenMsgStatus> loginMCall = service.sendMessage(userCookie, type, route_id, user_id, passenger_id, passenger_status, text);
```

Answer (score 4):

to add cookie header to okhttp request headers , add this in Interceptor:

`request= request.newBuilder().addHeader("Cookie", sessionIdAndToken).build();`

Ref:https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors as mentioned by @Alexander Mironov

Full Example code here: Hope it helps you

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingInterceptor.class);
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        request = processRequest(request);
        logger.info("Sending request with url:{} and connection status:{} and request headers:{}",
                request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers());

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        logger.info("Received response for url:{} and time taken:{} and response headers as:{}",
                response.request().url(), (t2 - t1) / 1e6d, response.headers());

        response = processResponse(response);
        return response;
    }
    //Add cookies for all subsequent requests
    private Request processRequest(Request request) {
        if(!request.url().toString().contains("/v1/authorize")) {
            final EmployeeSession session = getSession();
            StringBuilder etokenAndUId = new StringBuilder("etoken=");
            etokenAndUId.append(session.getEtoken()).append(";").append("uId=").append(session.getUId());
            logger.info("inside processRequest for all subsequent requests, sending cookies as etokenAndUId values:{}", etokenAndUId.toString());
            request= request.newBuilder().addHeader("Cookie", etokenAndUId.toString()).build();
        }
        return request;
    }

    //Extract cookies from login url
    private Response processResponse(Response response) {
        if(response.request().url().toString().contains("/v1/authorize")) {
            final List<String> cookieHeaders = response.headers("Set-Cookie");
            String etoken = "", uId = "";
            for (String cookieHeader : cookieHeaders) {
                if(cookieHeader.contains("etoken=")) {
                    etoken = cookieHeader.substring(7, cookieHeader.indexOf(';'));
                }
                else if(cookieHeader.contains("uId=")) {
                    uId = cookieHeader.substring(4, cookieHeader.indexOf(';'));
                }
            }
            logger.info("inside processResponse found cookies from login url response: etoken:{} and uid:{}", etoken, uId);
            setSession(etoken, uId, "c1");
            logger.info("current employee session:{}", getSession());
        }
        return response;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can add Cookie through retrofit using interceptor which is best solution for us to dynamically manage cookie in api request.**

I have tried with **JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager)** Which is not Work in my case. So I use Interceptor for this which also work with Dependency Injection n(Dagger as well as Koin).

**Step1:** Create **ReceivedCookiesInterceptor** class to receive cookies.

**Java Code: ReceivedCookiesInterceptor.java**

```
public class ReceivedCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());

    if (!originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie").isEmpty()) {
        HashSet<String> cookies = new HashSet<>();

        for (String header : originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie")) {
          cookies.add(header);
        }

        Preferences.getDefaultPreferences().edit()
                .putStringSet(Preferences.PREF_COOKIES, cookies)
                .apply();
    }

    return originalResponse;
} 
}
```

**Kotlin Code: ReceivedCookiesInterceptor.Kt**

```
class ReceivedCookiesInterceptor : Interceptor {
        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
            val originalResponse: Response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
            if (originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie").isNotEmpty()) {
                val cookies: HashSet<String> = HashSet()
                for (header in originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie")) {
                    cookies.add(header)
                }
                preferenceProvider.putStringSet("PREF_COOKIES", cookies)  
                // Prefrence Provider In My SharedPrefrence Object
            }
            return originalResponse
        }
    }
```

**Step2: Create AddCookiesInterceptorclass to Store cookies.**

**Java Code: AddCookiesInterceptorclass.java**

```
public class AddCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
    HashSet<String> preferences = (HashSet) Preferences.getDefaultPreferences().getStringSet(Preferences.PREF_COOKIES, new HashSet<>());
    for (String cookie : preferences) {
        builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
        Log.v("OkHttp", "Adding Header: " + cookie); // This is done so I know which headers are being added; this interceptor is used after the normal logging of OkHttp
    }

    return chain.proceed(builder.build());
}
}
```

**Kotlin Code: AddCookiesInterceptorclass.kt**

```
        class AddCookiesInterceptor : Interceptor {
        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
            val builder: Request.Builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
            val prefCookies: HashSet<String> =
                preferenceProvider.getStringSet("PREF_COOKIES", HashSet())
            for (cookie in prefCookies) {
                builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie)
            }
            return chain.proceed(builder.build())
        }
    }
```

**Step3: Add those intercepter inside your okHttpClientObject**

**Java Code: For Adding intercepter in Retrofit Request**

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
     okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new AddCookiesInterceptor());
    okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor());
```

**Kotlin Code: For Adding Interceptor in Retrofit Request**

```
   val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .connectionSpecs(specs)
        .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(AddCookiesInterceptor())
        .addInterceptor(ReceivedCookiesInterceptor())
```

Comment: Nice implementation for save cookie and implement in retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Kotlin code that invokes the `CookieManager` within an OkHttpClient (v3) that is passed to Retrofit2.

```
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cookieJar(object : CookieJar {
            private val cookieStore = HashMap<HttpUrl?, List<Cookie>>()
            private val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()

            override fun saveFromResponse(url: HttpUrl, cookies: List<Cookie>) {
                val host = url.host()
                cookieStore[HttpUrl.parse(host)] = cookies
                cookieManager.removeAllCookie()
                val cookies1 = cookieStore[HttpUrl.parse(host)]
                if (cookies1 != null) {
                    for (cookie in cookies1) {
                        val cookieString =
                            cookie.name() + "=" + cookie.value() + "; path=" + cookie.path()
                        cookieManager.setCookie(cookie.domain(), cookieString)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun loadForRequest(url: HttpUrl): List<Cookie> {
                val host = url.host()
                val cookies = cookieStore[HttpUrl.parse(host)]
                return cookies ?: ArrayList()
            }
        })
        .build()


    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true)

    val retrofit2 = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            // converter factory for converting JSON to object
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(client)
            .build()
```

And in your build.gradle `dependencies`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Interceptor**

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.http.*

interface FileService {
    companion object {
        private var fileService: FileService? = null
        fun getInstance(cookie: String): FileService {
            if (fileService == null) {
                fileService = Retrofit
                    .Builder()
                    .baseUrl("xxxxxx")
//                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    //add cookie
                    .client(OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(Interceptor { chain ->
                        chain.proceed(
                            chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Cookie", cookie).build()
                        );
                    }).build())
                    .build()
                    .create(FileService::class.java)
            }
            return fileService!!
        }
    }
@GET("link")
Call<CbGet> getData();
}
```