# App using old session file after session_regenerate_id()

Tags: php, session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 0;
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 5;
```

After running the following code, why is my $_SESSION['user_id'] still 0 when I access it later? Am I misunderstanding how session_regenerate_id() is supposed to work? Or is it an issue that I need to address elsewhere?

I can see that two session files have been created in C:\xampp\tmp, but I don't understand why the old file is being used.

My example is me trying to understand why I could not access $_SESSION['user_id'] that I would set after running session_start and session_regenerate_id at the very beginning of my .php file:

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 9; // i am unable to access this because my app is using the old file
```

Appreciate any help with this.

> Didn't you check the session.use_trans_sid php.ini option?

In my php.ini, I have `session.use_trans_sid=0` and another suggestion mentioned i do the following as well `session.use_strict_mode=1`. Still not working after these two edits.

> Note: i assume that they are 2 different https/http calls (the two
> codes starting with session_start() ... ) Can you see what all is
> stored in the 2nd file in the Session before and after you do the
> session_start? you can do a print_r($_SESSION) and do it before you
> regenerate as well I bet there is some code in between your lines that
> you haven't shared, is doing something to the session_start

I actually simplified my code down to the example in my post, and you can see it [here](https://i.gyazo.com/c26495dbc85a5ceb0cf05beb7fc81e99.png). This way, we are not worried about any other code.

I cleared my tmp folder and ran the code. Here are the resulting files with session_regenerate_id() commented out:

First File - https://pastebin.com/mBhQCrF3

addrelease.php output is 9 for 'user_id'

I commented out the line that sets the 'user_id' to 9 to see what happens next time I log on

Second File - https://pastebin.com/QNJ6S7sY

As expected, a new file with 8 as 'user_id'

Now I will clear the tmp folder (and restart server) again and do the same with session_regenerate_id() in the code. More specifically, this is what loginuser.php will run now:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = 8;

session_regenerate_id();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = 9;

$response['success'] = true;
$response['username'] = "test";

echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

This time, since we regenerate the id, there should be two files after loginuser.php is finished. I can't tell which one was created first, but we can see that one has 'user_id' set as 9 while the other has 'user_id' at 8:

File 1: https://pastebin.com/ba1vAmjd
File 2: https://pastebin.com/H9kDfdvt

After this, the output given by addrelease.php once it's finished is 8.

With the following change to loginuser.php, we can also get an idea of what 'user_id' is before it exits and addrelease.php runs the second session_start() call:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = 8;

session_regenerate_id();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = 10;

$response['message'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$response['success'] = false;
$response['username'] = "test";

echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

I clear tmp folder and restart servers again. This time, 'user_id' output is 10. So we can see that loginuser.php is using the correct file, while addrelease.php does not:

File 1: https://pastebin.com/7MpRMbge
File 2: https://pastebin.com/p6RUxH8F

Hopefully I have supplied enough in response to your comment.

**EDIT:** Also, I don't know if this is significant, but there is a another activity (dashboard activity) between my login activity and my add release activity that does not trigger a .php file.

Comment: Didn't you check the  session.use_trans_sid php.ini option? Because according to docs, if it is set to true, and you had made some output before calling session_regenerate_id(), the old session ID continues to be used. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Comment: @IliaYatsenko Hi, please see my edit answering your question!

Comment: *"Still not working after these two edits."* - do the server gets restarted?

Comment: Note: i assume that they are 2 different https/http calls (the two codes starting with session_start() ... )

Can you see what all is stored in the 2nd file in the Session before and after you do the session_start? you can do a print_r($_SESSION) and do it before you regenerate as well

I bet there is some code in between your lines that you haven't shared, is doing something to the session_start

Comment: @BagusTesa I restarted my server a few times and still nothing. Going to read through Rajan's comment now.

Comment: @Rajan Hi, please see my edits, hopefully with this we can find what is going on...

Comment: When you say that your "app" is still using the old session, can you give us a better idea of the structure of your app? Unless you pass a `true` argument when regenerating ( `session_regenerate_id( true );` ) the old session will still exist, but your browser should have received new cookie settings in the response headers of that script which would switch the session ID for all *subsequent* http requests. If you're in your browser, look at the Developer tools > Application tab and see what happens to the session cookie when you run the script

Comment: @BenD it's an android app specifically, so when i say it's using the old session, i mean that activities after the login activity are using a different session.

Comment: could you try this on PHP cmd https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php and let us see the result

Comment: @marlo here are my results to that https://i.gyazo.com/f188cecb8447fde4da66bf3d93391f7a.png

Comment: @dan how about from `session_start();` to `echo json_encode($response);`

Comment: @marlo you'd like to to run my own code in the command line?

Comment: @dan sorry, I just tried. `Warning: Undefined global variable $_SESSION`. I thought that it could be debugged on the interactive shell. my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after seeing that session was working correctly on my PC browser, I assumed from there that the issue was perhaps purely with how I set up something in my code for the Android app.

As it turns out, my CookieJar implementation was non-persistent. Using [PersistentCookieJar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881775/automatic-cookie-handling-with-okhttp-3) instead, I was able to have cookies persist between my activities on the app.

So for anyone having a similar issue, I would suggest reading through this thread and if nothing works, be sure to check your cookie management implementation for the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think i know the core issue and have the solution as well.

From the json_encode, i assume that some frontend is querying these php files and a json response is sent. So, the session is being written to multiple times.

After writing to the session, IN EVERY FILE that you write sessions to, but PER HTTP/HTTPS request, please do an explicit session_write_close() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php .

So, what i mean is that let us assume you have frontendpage1.php that has the html for the user. If you are writing to sessions in this file, do a session_write_close() at the end. Further, if, as a result of an ajax call or something, you have file1.php, file2.php and file3.php used, where they are all writing to the session, do session_write_close() at the end of the last write of the session.

I remember reading that this good practice when sessions are written to frequently.

I had a similar issue with sessions and this worked well

Remember to do a session_start() at the start of each unique browser request/ajax request

**EDIT**
2nd Option: I think you have a corrupt cookie PHPSESSID . If you try with a browser that doesn't have any cookies set (for the server that is hosting your files), i bet you see the right session values.

Another way to test is, use the same browser, but just add The only thing I can think of is a corrupt cookie PHPSESSID (the default) or whatever cookie you are using, but just add session_name("myStackOverFlowID"); before session_start(); in both these files. the new session_name is not highly recommended: it is just to test.

**EDIT: another option**

Do the session_write_close()  before regenerating the ID

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion but my addrelease.php is still seeing 8 as the output: https://i.gyazo.com/5ac608d8b4d4a667250d1abb3de44328.png

and here are some outputs i logged where we can see that the session IDs are still different between files: https://i.gyazo.com/e1a03dfa9d0644f6e15af5291955233c.png

Comment: See my Edit above.. pls check on multiple browsers and sessions

Comment: for you second edit, I am not sure how to go about testing within a browser given that i only have android app functionality at the moment. I am going to try moving the session_write_close() and let you know.

Comment: Moving the session_write_close() before regenerating the ID results in the following message caught my okhttp:

<b>Warning</b>:  session_regenerate_id(): Session ID cannot be regenerated when there is no active session in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\releasesApp\loginuser.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />

Comment: adding the session_name before session_start() in both files still resulted in different sessions between the files: https://i.gyazo.com/823c1e9c02ddbf4069e9142891b461ba.png

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we know that an Android App is involved!

1. Check if any part of the App code is storing cookies, etc., in cache
2. Track time using hrtime(true); (recommended instead of microtime for accuracy) see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime.php
3. If possible, clear out the App data on that android phone and test on a different android phone as well

Comment: I will look into step 2. Could you explain how I go about steps 1 and 3?

Comment: Step 1: i don't know what all libraries you are using. For Step3: https://www.google.com/search?q=clear+app+data+android&oq=clear+app+data+android . Install your android App on a different app and see

Comment: I'm seeing now that the session appears to be working in Chrome, but not on my phone.