# Another set-cookie attribute for secure flag

Tags: security, cookies, browser, bluemix-app-scan

After adding the following tag in web.config

```html
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

I am getting "Set-Cookie:Secure" in every response header. But
I can see there are duplicate "Set-Cookie" attributes in the headers as below
[image: IBM AppScan]

IBM AppScan is raising an exception - Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie. I have gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305814/are-multiple-cookie-headers-allowed-in-an-http-request) and [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) but I am not clear if a response header can have another "Set-Cookie" attribute for secure flag.

Comment: You can have multiple `Set-Cookie` response headers - but each one sets an individual, complete cookie. The information for _one_ cookie can not be split across multiple such headers. What your screenshot shows, is two cookies being set - the session cookie, and then one with the name `Secure` only, and no additional info such as value, path, expiry ...

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @CBroe